# dotNetBar component properties not load in property panel visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, dotnetbar

I have  install visual Studio 2022 and DotNetBar
every thing is ok but when using the DotnetBar Component in Windows Form the properties of that component Not load in property windows.

[the picture of this problem attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuduD.png)

Comment: First save or build and then try

Comment: I did but not worked

Comment: If you are having preview version then update visual studio with latest version, this bug was in preview version and its resolved

Comment: As I know  DotNetBar is abandoned for couple years, forum support is read-only

Comment: DotNetBar is not anymore updated since few years.

Answer (score 0):

Some times happens to me , you need to resize the right panel, top and bottom to see all the properties.